# How to add years to an epoch time using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, epoch

I have the epoch time `1196110849` which is `[Mon, 26 Nov 2007 21:00:49 GMT]` in Human readable form. 
How can I add 5 years to the epochTime using PHP and get the corresponding epochTime after adding the 5 years?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$newEpochTime = strtotime("+5 years", $epoch);
```

And for the sake of being modern:

```
$newEpochTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $epoch)
                    ->add(new DateInterval('P5Y'))
                    ->format('U');
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're using PHP 5.3 or better, then [`DateTime::add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or by using a [relative time format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) like dev-null-dweller suggested.

Comment: Epoch time already doesn't worry about leap seconds.   But there's no reason you can't use `strtotime` to figure out how many seconds "5 years from now" is (which your answer is almost guaranteed to be wrong for, since the vast majority of 5-year-periods have at least one leap day, and some have two).

Comment: @MarkReed I was not aware of the relative time formats in PHP pre-5.2/5.3. I wish I had been, though, as it would have saved me some past headaches.